# What is the correct way to write extensions generically?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have seen examples to write class extensions for generics a couple of different ways.  I am going to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) as an example.

1)

```
public static class Extensions<Src, Tgt>
{
    public static Tgt TransferData(this Src source)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Tgt>();
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Src, Tgt>(source);
    }
}
```

2)

```
public static class Extensions2
{
    public static Tgt TransferData<Src, Tgt>(this Src source)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Tgt>();
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Src, Tgt>(source);
    }
}
```

Which is better?  Why?  Is the first one even correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the first one isn't correct. Extension methods have to be defined in a top-level, static **non-generic** class.

Additionally, I'd suggest complying with the naming conventions for type parameters, too:

```
public static class Extensions2
{
    public static TTarget TransferData<TSource, TTarget>(this TSource source)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TTarget>();
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TSource, TTarget>(source);
    }
}
```